# Copying blank Template to next available Column within same Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, copy, range

I'm working on a project for work at the moment and I have a rudimentary knowledge of excel, even less so when it comes to macros and VBA. I searched for hours yesterday trying to find something similar to what I'm needing, but the code that was found was being used for far more complicated tasks.

I have a range of cells *A1:M36". This is the blank template. I have the button created but have no idea how to finish the macro. What I would like is that whenever the button is clicked, a new blank template will be placed to the next empty column.  I think I would like to have the offset function here [(0,1)?] 
so that it looks more aesthetically pleasing, which would make the 2nd Template starting in column "O". Currently I'm reading through tutorials to try to figure it out myself, but was hoping I could get some more direct feedback through here.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Bender

Comment: A "a next empty column" in a "blanc template" would all the time be column A:A... Do you have, at least, column headers in this so named "blanc template"? Does it contain some specific format?

Comment: I am not asking tor the sake of asking... I can supply a solution, but only if I would understand what your question means. The problem would be to determine "a next empty column". If not column headers, is there a special format on a specific row of the blank template last column? I would be able to use it like reference, but I need to exactly know what this 'format' means...

Comment: It was originally created as a paper document be printed out, I found the .xls format and wanted to create this for my new job, at a previous place of employment there was the exact same setup to replace all the paper being wasted.

Comment: I will check with my superiors to see if I can send the template to you, as it could be proprietary knowledge and I don't want to risk being fired for that. I will try the code as soon as I get back to my desk and let you know as soon as possible! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are there some other records to be copied, except  the template format? I thought that your initial template has already been filled with data and that's why I thought that only the format is necessary... If you need to everything be copied, it will be enough to choose `Paste` instead of `PasteSpecial` and delete last code line...

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry, just made this account this morning. Hopefully I am answering you correctly. A1:M1 is the column header, with the title of the document.  A2:M34 are blank areas for the End User to fill in (this page is used for troubleshooting purposes). The End user will type in the necessary information. Whenever a new one is needed, They will click the macro and a brand new template will show up, starting at N1.

Again, forgive me if I'm wording this wrong. 

The code you provided does not copy+paste a new template into the desired location.

Comment: It should not include any information the end user has filled out. Each time the macro is used, another "form" will be placed to the right of the last used. No data is to be carried over, only the formats of the cells. I apologize, I'm struggling to break this down further.

Comment: In such a case, your question as it has been formulated does not have an answer... You must use a different sheet which will contain the template and the copying will be done based on this sheet content. I will adapt te code accordingly (I will name the new sheet "Template")...

Comment: Adapted the code to do what (I understood) you need. Please test it and confirm that it does what is supposed to do...

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy all template, without what your users filled, you need another sheet (named "Template" in my next code):

```
Sub testCopyTemplate()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shT As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastCol As Long
   Set shT = Worksheets("Template")
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet where you fill the data
   Set rng = shT.Range("A1:M36")
   lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   rng.Copy sh.Cells(1, lastCol + IIf(lastCol = 1, 0, 1))'here it deals with the case of an empty (active) sheet, when column A:A must be used...
End Sub
```